# Random Forest importances vs Feature Permutation: cummulative sum of importances are 1 and 0.1, respectively. Make sense?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I am performing feature selection by using two methods: MDI (RandomForest importances) and Feature Permutation, in order to compare what are the features considered relevant for both methods. My dataset is full categorical (features with values 0 o 1). The importances obtained for both methods for an specific feature (the most important one, for instance) are `0.30` and `0.039`, respectively. If I apply the cummulative sum over the importances from both methods, I get `1` for MDI and around `0.1` for Feature Permutation. I don't know if it is expected or not to get values in those ranges for Feature Permutation.